# Implementing worker threads (in Linux): How offensive is this?

Tags: linux, multithreading, posix, pthreads

```
#include <pthread.h>
static void * worker_thread(void *);

void some_func(void)
{
    pthread_t * tmp;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
    if (NULL != tmp)
    {
        if (!pthread_create(tmp, NULL, worker_thread, (void *)tmp))
            pthread_detach(*tmp);
        else
            free(tmp);
    }
}

static void * worker_thread(void * p)
{
    /* do work */
    free(p);
    return(NULL);
}
```

Comment: I find your offense offensive.

Comment: You have a race condition. You could end up freeing tmp before you actually use it to detach the thread. Why not just use a stack variable?

Comment: beware ppl could flag it

Comment: anyway, the code looks suspicious. i don't think it'S correct. although i lack pthread knowledge

Comment: I get that there could be a race condition.  Can I really get away using the stack? I would've thought the pthread_t structure had to exist for the OS to task switch etc.

Comment: @litb: the code is pretty much as basic as it gets, except for the race condition with the heap-allocated pointer to the thread structure.

Comment: It will exist in the kernel. You're gonna get a copy of stuff that the user-space library wants to interact with the kernel task.

Comment: "You're gonna get a copy of stuff that ... kernel task".  Could you point me to an elaboration of what you meant here?

Comment: @Jamie: No, the OS doesn't need the thread identifier (pthread_t) to exist for anything.

Comment: @Jamie: Just that the kernel will manage your threads. It doesn't matter what you do with the identifier if you don't need it (except if you free it and then use it :p). Also, the thread can detach itself. Call pthread_self() to get the thread identifier from within the new thread. Often you see: pthread_detach(pthread_self());

Comment: Thanks and much appreciated.  Very useful information Jason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I learned from the comments is that the `pthread_t` structure isn't required to be 'alive' for the duration of thread (which is what I thought and why I used malloc); a stack variable is fine.  What I ended up doing was based on Jason Coco's comment:

```
#include <pthread.h>

static void * worker_thread(void *);

void start_worker(void * arg)
{
    pthread_t tmp;
    (void)pthread_create(& tmp, NULL, worker_thread, arg))
}

static void * worker_thread(void * p)
{
    /* do work */

    /* finished work */
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    return (p);
}
```

Comment: Just one more thing - it's probably a bad idea to ignore the return value of `pthread_create`. Otherwise your program might just deadlock or do the wrong thing...